# jQuery slimScroll & Blur on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used jQuery slimScroll, for one div Box. Now I want to use Blur on Scroll  so I can use these Effect. 
The Problem when I scroll in the div-Box nothing happend.

```
http://codepen. io/sota0805/pen/pqLcv
```

What I want to do. 
If somebody scroll in the div-box the background in the div box should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#div-BoxId").on("scroll", function(){this.style.background="red"})
```